# How can I write this query using the laravel query builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, common-table-expression

I'm on laravel 5.1 using postgres as the DB. I have a fiddle here in case it helps understand my issue: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ELU6xinJrXiQJ6u6VH5/4

```
with properties as (
    select 
        properties.*, 
        json_agg(property_fields.*) as property_fields 
    from 
        properties 
    left join fields as property_fields 
        on property_fields.parent = 'property' and property_fields.parent_id = properties.id 
    group by properties.id, properties.deal_id, properties.address
)

select 
    deals.*, 
    json_agg(properties.*) as deal_properties, 
    json_agg(deal_fields.*) as deal_fields
from deals

left join properties on deals.id = properties.deal_id
left join fields deal_fields on deal_fields.parent = 'deal' and deal_fields.parent_id = deals.id

group by deals.id, deals.name
order by deals.id
```

Writing most of this is fairly straight forward. The problem I'm having is with the `with properties as (...)` block. I've tried something like:

```
DB::statement('WITH properties AS ( ... )')
    ->table('deals')
    ->select(' deals.*, json_agg(properties.*) as deal_properties,  ')
    ...
    ->get();
```

But I notice the execution stop after `DB::statement()`

Is there a method in the Query Builder that I'm missing? How can I prefix my query with the `WITH properties AS (...)` statement?

I think it should also be noted that I'm trying to implement a Repository Pattern and I can't just wrap a `DB::statement()` around the whole query.

Comment: Have you tried `DB::select('...')`?

Comment: try this: DB::statement(DB::raw('WITH properties AS ( ... )'))

Answer (score 2):

I've created a package for common table expressions: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-cte

```php
$query = 'select properties.*, [...]';

DB::table('deals')
    ->withExpression('properties', $query)
    ->leftJoin([...])
    ->[...]
```

You can also provide a query builder instance:

```php
$query = DB::table('properties')
    ->select('properties.*', [...])
    ->leftJoin([...])
    ->[...]

DB::table('deals')
    ->withExpression('properties', $query)
    ->leftJoin([...])
    ->[...]
```

Comment: Excellent package Jonas! I've moved on from the problem but I hope someone in the future finds this helpful.

Answer (score -1):

if you want some data fetch from a table you can use this type of code

`$user = DB::table('table name')->where('name', 'John')->where('height','!>',"7")->select('table fields which you want to fetch')->get();`

Or try using the larevel Eloquent ORM which will make things easier with the database.

for more example or reference

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries

Answer (score -1):

I think you can actually do this with eager loading,
 assuming that the relationships are set up correctly.
 (More reading here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

So I think you'd be able to add something like

```
->with(['properties' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('field')
        ->leftJoin('join statement')
        ->groupBy('field1', 'field2');
}])
```

Comment: I want to use the query builder for this, not eloquent.